# Deploying an Amplify App using Terraform Without Relying on Git

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-amplify, terraform-provider-aws

Is there a way to deploy an Amplify app with Terraform without using a Git repository? The AWS console has an option for manual deployments as shown in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/manual-deploys.html). But I have searched far and wide and it seems that there is no documentation on how to do this on Terraform. I prefer to use manual deployment as using a GitHub repo requires a personal access token, and this is for a group project, and I don't want to end up sharing a personal access token just to get a group project to work. The code for the Terraform I have so far is shown here, which relies on a GitHub repo:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 3.27"
    }
  }

  required_version = ">= 0.14.9"
}

variable "region" {
  type        = string
  default     = "us-east-1"
  description = "AWS region used for server deployment"
}

provider "aws" {
  profile = "default"
  region  = var.region
}

resource "aws_amplify_app" "wildrydes-site" {
  name       = "amp-terr-test"
  repository = "https://github.com/owner/repo"
  # GitHub personal access token
  access_token = "some_access_token"

  # The default rewrites and redirects added by the Amplify Console.
  custom_rule {
    source = "/<*>"
    status = "404"
    target = "/index.html"
  }

  #Auto Branch Creation
  enable_auto_branch_creation = true

  # The default patterns added by the Amplify Console.
  auto_branch_creation_patterns = [
    "*",
    "*/**",
  ]

  auto_branch_creation_config {
    # Enable auto build for the created branch.
    enable_auto_build = true
  }
}
```

Comment: It does appear that the AWS API only allows automated deployments with SCM repositories. You cannot automate the deployment with other methods. If you want to manually deploy the application, then you need to manage the amplify application and its associated configuration without specifying the repository in the resource, and then manually deploy the application within the console. You can update the application settings with TF+AWS, but not update the deployment in this way. Is that ok?

Comment: @MattSchuchard our group just ended up making a group burner account on GitHub. So we are good for now.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not (yet) supported by Terraform. There is an open feature request for that: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/24720